# Extract Options From Dropdown List Extracted From Website

Tags: python, parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I've been trying (unsuccessfully) to solve this problem for a few hours and need some help. I used Firebug to extract a couple hundred lines of HTML that look like this:

```
<option value="1b4f4aed-cf1f-4b39-ae27">Foo</option>
<option value="1a05f93f-dd51-449d-b039">Bar</option>
<option value="f62d2d29-29fc-4f7c-9331">Bacon</option>
```

I saved the lines to a text file. What I want is a (Python preferred, with Ruby as an alternative) script to open process and close the file. The processing should result in a new text file being saved that looks like this:

```
Foo
Bar
Bacon
```

That's it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: I'm such a beginner... as far as I got was Googling and searching StackOverflow for things like "parse HTML", "parse HTML with Python", "extract options from dropdown list", etc. I found a bunch of interesting stuff (BeautifulSoup, Scrapy, YouTube videos, etc.) and wrote up some pseudocode but I kind of in that "lost" stage. Tired and going to bed now. I'm sorry if I am posting too soon in my struggle. To give you an idea of my level, I'm halfway throw a new beginner's book on Python. Thks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your comment above, I would suggest BeautifulSoup with anything HTML related. Since you are early in your learning stage, probably best to associate 'HTML' with 'BeautifulSoup' (and not [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) :) ). Here is a very basic example:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: html = """
<option value="1b4f4aed-cf1f-4b39-ae27">Foo</option>
<option value="1a05f93f-dd51-449d-b039">Bar</option>
<option value="f62d2d29-29fc-4f7c-9331">Bacon</option>
"""

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

In [4]: for option in soup.find_all('option'):
   ...:     print option.text
   ...:     
Foo
Bar
Bacon
```

Here we pass our HTML to `BeautifulSoup` and assign it to the `soup` variable. Now we have an object that contains our HTML and a large amount of methods for interacting with it in a user-friendly way. Here, we use the `find_all` method (documentation [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)) to find all `option` tags in our HTML. Now when we iterate, we are iterating through `Tag` objects, which have their own special properties/methods. Here we pick one of them (`.text`) to display the text of the `Tag` element (which in this case will be the text enclosed in the tag).

Comment: +1 for the part about not using regular expressions to parse HTML :)

Comment: @JoelCornett Ha, I wonder how many people that post has 'saved' (I'm one, for sure :) ).

Comment: Thank you very much @RocketDonkey! That solved my problem and gave me a learning boost. As an exercise (or exercises) I will extend what you  posted to work with files, data structures, and iterators. From there, I will do some BeautifulSoup tutorials and documentation reading. Seems really powerful and usable. Anyway, thanks again :)

Comment: @chrisco No problem at all, happy to help :) One thing that will be interesting for you is to get a basic knowledge of BeautifulSoup down, continue your studies into data structures, etc., and then come back to BeautifulSoup after you have a solid foundation. You'll then be able to dig into what is actually going on ('What is a `Tag`, actually? How could I create my own `Tag`?') and open up a whole new level of understanding. You're in for a good time :)